# rJava Module could not be be found

Tags: r, rjava

I am trying to load the rJava package to R 3.1.1.

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
library(rJava)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Rohan-PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Now the following exists I have checked it:

```
'C:/Users/Rohan-PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll'
```

I have also checked the file permission and everyone has Full Control.

I have search a few other post and found a similar problem, but not the module could not be found. Some mentions about JMV which I also have.

I am running Windows 8 x64

Answer (score 2):

Running through these commands works for me:

```
> options(java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\")
> library(rJava)
> library(RJDBC)
> vDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath="C:/java/dbeaver-3.0.0/drivers/vertica/vertica-jdk5-6.1.2-0.jar")
> vertica <- dbConnect(vDriver, "jdbc:vertica://xx.x.xxx.xxx:5433/db", "vertica", "vertica")
> myframe = dbGetQuery(vertica, "select Payment_Key, Payment_Description from Payment_Detail")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It worked for me after i added the R library path to the environment variables list on my windows 7.

So,

Add 'C:/Users/Rohan-PC/Documents/R/win-library/3.1' this path to the Path variables list under System variables list(not to be confused with the PATH variable under User variables). Restart R and try loading the library. It works!!!!!